# Failed to get bean from Spring custom Condition

Tags: spring, kotlin

I tried to create a custom Condition/Conditional to setup my custom condition to activate a bean

The custom `Condtion` class.

```kotlin
class FeatureEnabledCondition : Condition {
    companion object {
        private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FeatureEnabledCondition::class.java)
    }
    override fun matches(context: ConditionContext, metadata: AnnotatedTypeMetadata): Boolean = runBlocking {
        val manager = context.beanFactory?.getBean(FeatureFlagManager::class.java)
        log.debug("annotations; ${metadata.annotations}")
        metadata.getAnnotationAttributes(ConditionalOnFeatureEnabled::class.java.name, true)?.let {
            val feature = it["value"] as FeatureName
            manager?.isEnabled(feature) ?: false
        } ?: false
    }
}
```

And the `@Conditional` metadata class.

```kotlin
@Target(AnnotationTarget.TYPE, AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@MustBeDocumented
@Conditional(FeatureEnabledCondition::class)
annotation class ConditionalOnFeatureEnabled(
    val value: FeatureName
)
```

When I tried to write a test to verify it like this.

```kotlin
@SpringBootTest(classes = [FeatureEnabledConditionTest.FeatureEnabledConditionTestConfig::class])
class FeatureEnabledConditionTest {

    // @Import(SimpleFeatureFlagManager::class)
    @Configuration
    class FeatureEnabledConditionTestConfig {
        @Bean
        @ConditionalOnFeatureEnabled(value = FeatureName.LOCATION_WALLET)
        fun testBean(): TestBean = TestBean()
    }

    class TestBean()

    @MockkBean
    lateinit var featureFlagManager: FeatureFlagManager

    @Autowired
    lateinit var testBean: TestBean

    @Test
    fun `test feature is on`() = runTest {
        coEvery { featureFlagManager.isEnabled(any()) } returns true
        testBean shouldNotBe null
    }
}
```

The `context.beanFactory?.getBean(FeatureFlagManager::class.java)` raised a `NoSuchBeanException`, even I added a `@Bean fun featureManager():FeatureManager=mockk()`.

1. I am not sure the Conditional is working when depends on a bean.
2. How to test it?

Comment: The conditional runs before/while the context is getting created, the mockbean is created afer that by a `TestExecutionLIstener`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the context initialization issue mentioned by [M Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum), finally use `ApplicationContextRunner` to load the context manually.

```kotlin
class FeatureEnabledConditionTest {

    @Configuration
    class FeatureEnabledConditionTestConfig {
        @Bean
        @ConditionalOnFeatureEnabled(value = FeatureName.WALLET)
        fun testBean(): TestBean = TestBean()
    }

    class TestBean()

    private val contextRunner = ApplicationContextRunner()
        .withUserConfiguration(FeatureEnabledConditionTestConfig::class.java)

    @Test
    fun `test feature is on`() = runTest {
        contextRunner
            .withBean(
                FeatureFlagManager::class.java,
                {
                    val mock = mockk<FeatureFlagManager>()
                    coEvery { mock.isEnabled(any()) } returns true
                    mock
                }
            )
            .run { context ->
                assertThat(context).hasSingleBean(TestBean::class.java)
            }
    }

    @Test
    fun `test feature is off`() = runTest {
        contextRunner
            .withBean(
                FeatureFlagManager::class.java,
                {
                    val mock = mockk<FeatureFlagManager>()
                    coEvery { mock.isEnabled(any()) } returns false
                    mock
                }
            )
            .run { context ->
                assertThat(context).doesNotHaveBean(TestBean::class.java)
            }
    }
}
```